# what are the appropriate font types for dot matrix when printing documents

Tags: printing, fonts, crystal-reports, dot-matrix

I have set the page size and margin for the crystal report for dot matrix setting, but when I print the document.

The font is not clear. What are the types of font that I can use that can display the page clearly when printing the documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it set from report side, open file menu -> option (or report option) , then navigate font tab. where you define the font and style. you can check via preview and final save and deploy.

for dot matrix font check this:
https://forums.asp.net/t/1940447.aspx?What+is+the+suitable+font+for+Dot+Matrix+Printer+to+print+RDLC+

Comment: @khalif, "the image that..." not understand this things. can you upload an image for your crystal report setting and your dotmatrix copy